# R sf package equivalent to R rgeos gProject function and, if so, can it work on polygons rather than points

Tags: r, sf, rgeos

I'm processing some very large 3D POLYGONZ shapefiles (100s of thousands of small triangles) representing a "fence diagram" (multiple vertical profiles) from a 3D geologic model.  Attempting to "dissolve" (using group_by() |> summarize()) the 3D polygons directly scrambled the results. I was able to cast the sf plys to sp points, project them into 2D distance/elevation space using gProject, re-polygonize, and dissolve those polygons and they look great.  However, when I cast the dissolved polygons back to points, project them back into 3D using gInterpolate, and try to rebuild the polygons, things are scrambled again.

Comment: The `sf::st_transform` function works on any spatial vector geometry (point, polygon, line).